# Scala yield IndexedSeq conversion

Tags: scala

I have following code snippet:

```
val tiles = for {
      x <- 0 to bitmap.length by tileSize
      y <- 0 to bitmap(0).length by tileSize
    } yield new Tile[Number](x, y, tileSize, tileSize,
     data = for {tx <- x to x + tileSize - 1;
          ty <- y to y + tileSize - 1
          } yield (bitmap(tx)(ty)))
```

This can look complicated, but the idea behind is to create `Tile` objects for every XY position in 3-dimensional `bitmap` object. The 'nested' `yield` that is given as a `data` parameter into the `Tile`'s constructor is an `IndexedSeq[Number]`, which should be converted to an `Array[Number]` to match the type of the `data` parameter. The problem is that `toArray` method doesn't exist for the final `yield`ed object:

```
val tiles = for {
      x <- 0 to bitmap.length by tileSize
      y <- 0 to bitmap(0).length by tileSize
    } yield new Tile[Number](x, y, tileSize, tileSize,
     data = for {tx <- x to x + tileSize - 1;
          ty <- y to y + tileSize - 1
          } yield (bitmap(tx)(ty).toArray))
```

causes an error `Cannot resolve symbol toArray`, even though `yield (bitmap(tx)(ty).toArray))` is shown as `IndexedSeq[java.lang.Number]` in IntelliJIDEA and theoretically should contain a definition of `toArray` method.

What is happening in the last `yield`? How can I convert resulting collection to an `Array`? I know, this code may and should be rewritten in simplier and more readable manner, but now I want to know, what is going on behind the curtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `toArray` to the final result of all the **for**, not to each `yield`.

You may do this:

```
val tiles = for {
      x <- 0 to bitmap.length by tileSize
      y <- 0 to bitmap(0).length by tileSize
    } yield new Tile[Number](x, y, tileSize, tileSize,
     data = (for {tx <- x to x + tileSize - 1;
          ty <- y to y + tileSize - 1
          } yield bitmap(tx)(ty)).toArray
```

However, this syntax is not encouraged in **Scala**, consider this snippet instead.

```
val tiles = for {
  x <- 0 to bitmap.length by tileSize
  y <- 0 to bitmap(0).length by tileSize
  data = for {
    tx <- x to x + tileSize - 1
    ty <- y to y + tileSize - 1
  } yield bitmap(tx)(ty)
  tile = new Tile[Number](x, y, tileSize, tileSize, data.toArray)
} yield tile
```